# Calculating a number by experience point correlation

Tags: java, loops, math, syntax, numbers

Looking at this RuneScape experience table: http://runescape.wikia.com/wiki/Experience/Table

You can see that an experience point amount correlates to a "level"

where:

```
if (xp < 83){
    level = 0;
}
else if (xp >= 83 && xp < 174){
    level = 1;
}
//etc
```

So when I save just the experience as a field for my player, how can I calculate the level they will be with their experience?

Without looping through 100 experience point integers.

i.e I don't want to do this: (Because a player will have many levels, meaning this will need to be looped many times)

```
for (int i =0; i < 100) {
  if (playersExperience < experienceRequiredForLevel(i){
    return i;
}
```

perhaps there is a faster way to do this?

Edit:
There is a formula to calculate the experience for level X here:

rsdo.net/rsdonline/guides/Experience%20formula.html

though I don't know how to reverse engineer that to find level instead

Comment: U can't because the experience can be between 2 points, it's never exactly 83 or 174, etc. Nonetheless a switch block is essentially looping

Comment: I used to design RuneScape Private Servers, and we used a `NavigableMap` (or just an array using binary search) to map experience to its respective level.  Good luck!

Comment: Have you tried seeing how fast it would be just using `if-else`s?

Comment: count down instead of up - then your loop will exit at the first match (highest level)

Comment: It's maybe possible to use maths to get a graph, which then can be easily read

Answer (score 0):

You can have a multiplier of X the experience levels. And you just take the integer part of division.

Ex if X=100: LVL1 = 100, LVL2 = 200; etc ...

In this case you just can just:

```
LVL = Experience / X;
Ex: 100 / 100 = 1 LVL, 200 / 100 = 2 ... etc
```

X can be any number.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How would this work, given that (for example) Level 1 is <= 83, level 2 is <= 174 etc...?

Comment: You should change the experience you get per LVL in such way that it is a multiplier when the LVL change.

Comment: There is a formula to calculate the experience for level X here: http://rsdo.net/rsdonline/guides/Experience%20formula.html
though I don't know how to reverse engineer that to find level instead

Comment: @Simion Surely only the owners of Runescape can do that?

Comment: That's exactly what I said I did not want to do, I even literally wrote that answer in my question explicitly to show I did not want that

Comment: Sorry, somehow i missed that, i removed that part.

Comment: It can be another solution to keep an array with LENGTH of maximum XP the player can have, and for each point of XP to store the LVL to which it belongs, but think this is a wrong solution, because if you look at the XP table of the very high LVL'd you can see numbers like: 26,068,632 , and is no reason why to store a such big array.

Answer (score 0):

You could use binary search to speed up things:

```
private static final int[] experiences={83, 174, ...};

int level(int experience) {
    // boundary check
    if (experience < experiences[0])
        return 0;
    if (experience >= experiences[experiences.length-1])
        return experiences.length;
    int minLevel = 0;
    int maxLevel = experiences.length;
    while (maxLevel - minLevel > 1) {
        int chk = (maxLevel+minLevel)/2;
        if (experience < experiences[chk])
            maxLevel = chk;
        if (experience >= experiences[chk])
            minLevel = chk;
    }
    return maxLevel;
}
```